# Number of Hamiltonian paths in the Hoffman-Singleton graph/Moore graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-paths

Does anyone happen to know how many Hamiltonian paths are in the Hoffman-Singleton graph, or have any idea on how I could count such paths?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686052/hamiltonian-paths-of-the-hoffman-singleton-graph

Comment: I think it is impossibly too large.